# How to rewrite URL using mod_rewrite to keep some part of URL and remove other

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use URL rewriting to keep some part of URL and remove other part using this simple code in .htaccess file located in my `localhost/test` folder:

```
RewriteRule ^remove/(.+)$ $1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule .* echo.php?final_url=$0
```

Now when I apply it to URL: `localhost/test/remove/keep/` I get `final_url` parameter containing `keep/keep` instead of expected `keep`.

Here is how I understand rewriting process:

1. First rewrite run: my URL gets rewrited to `localhost/test/keep/` (beacuse it matches 1st rule pattern) and than mathes second rule and its condition, so gets rewrited to: `localhost/test/echo.php?final_url=keep/`
2. Now second rewrite run goes: first rule pattern is no longer matched (becuse it doesn't start with remove/), so is the second rule (becuse now URL points to existing file: echo.php) so rewriting should end

Please correct my thinking and give detailed explanation what exactly is going on

Comment: Is `test/keep/` a real directory inside your site root dir?

Comment: @anubhava no, it is not